# Create React App cannot resolve local file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app

so I'm using absolute imports like so import: `import { Something } from 'some/random/path/in/my/app'`

but all of a sudden CRA is breaking saying `Module not found: Can't resolve 'some/random/path/in/my/app'` even though it's been importing it and working for a long time.

I've `rm -rf node_modules` => `npm i` and `npm run start` but I still get the issue, how can I resolve this?

Comment: try `import { Something } from './some/random/path/in/my/app'` and make sure the path is relative to the current file. I've never seen a webpack import work the way you are saying without some custom config.

Comment: I've added `NODE_PATH=src/` to my `.env` file. this has been working for a long time by the way, it's just randomly stopped which is odd

Comment: Do you have aliases setup?

Answer (score 0):

I think you shouldnt use an absolute path, Reacts point of view on your
`import { Something } from 'some/random/path/in/my/app` is as if its a module.

Try `import { Something } from './path/to/your/local/file`

Comment: you can use `NODE_PATH=src/` in your `.env` that I have been doing for ages. and it's normally perfectly fine

Comment: Wasnt it removed?

Answer (score 0):

You can create `jsconfig.json` files at the same level with `src` folder and add there following:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "src"
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

Then restart your app. I use this solution in many projects.